# Product page item validation PHP

Tags: php, validation, product, sanitization

I have a product page where the user can select X amount of items from a list of 5 different items.

Before the information can be submitted they must have at least one item in their cart.

This is an example of item 1 in the HTML:

```
<div class="quantityField" id="item1">
    <input id="qty1" name="qty1" class="qty" value="" type="text" placeholder="0" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <button type="button" id="addMac">Add</button>
</div>
```

And the PHP that I am trying to get to do this looks like this:

```
}elseif (!filter_var($qty1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT){
    exit("Error: You have no items in your cart.");
}elseif (!filter_var($qty2, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT){
    exit("Error: You have no items in your cart.");
}elseif (!filter_var($qty3, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT){
    exit("Error: You have no items in your cart.");
}elseif (!filter_var($qty4, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT){
    exit("Error: You have no items in your cart.");
}elseif (!filter_var($qty5, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT){
    exit("Error: You have no items in your cart.");
}
```

Now the user input needs to be validated as an int, 0 is allowed, but again there must be one item in the cart.

With how it's coded right now, it is requiring that there be at least 1 of EVERY item in the cart which is obviously not going to be what someone actually selects.

How can I adjust this to force the user to select a minimum of 1 item, but no maximum before proceeding to the invoice page?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to sum all the quantities and if it is greater than zero, then it is correct. Before that, however, it would be good to cast all quantity values to integer `(int) $qty1` etc. Maybe better is to use arrays here? Like `$qty[0]`, `$qty[1]`. Easier to maintenance.

Comment: Great idea, this worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <form action="" method="POST">
  <label for="ptoduct1">Product1:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="pro1"><br><br>
  <label for="ptoduct1">Product2:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="pro2"><br><br>
  <label for="ptoduct1">Product3:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="pro3"><br><br>
  <label for="ptoduct1">Product4:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="pro4"><br><br>
  <label for="ptoduct1">Product5:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fname" name="pro5"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
  </form>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $product1=$_POST['pro1'];
  $product2=$_POST['pro2'];
  $product3=$_POST['pro3'];
  $product4=$_POST['pro4'];
  $product5=$_POST['pro5'];
   echo $product1,' ' ,$product2,' ',$product3,' ',$product4,' 
  ',$product4;
  }
 ?>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if($product1>0 or $product2>0 or $product3 >0 or $product4 >0 or 
   $product5 >0){
   echo 'run';
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).